# An example about diagrams and graphs with Tikz on manual V2.10 Page 70 fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, examples

[image: A screenshot of the book]

My question is that I cannot compile the codes provided on page 70 in the TikZ Manual V2.10. I just add some packages but it cannot compile. Can anybody help? 
My codes are shown as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,positioning,arrows,graphs}
\begin{document}

\tikz [>=stealth', black!50, text=black, thick,
every new ->/.style = {shorten >=1pt},
graphs/every graph/.style = {edges=rounded corners},
skip loop/.style = {to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
nonterminal/.style = {
rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white,
bottom color=red!50!black!20, font=\itshape, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex},
terminal/.style = {
rounded rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=black!50, top color=white,
bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
shape = coordinate
]
\graph [grow right sep, branch down=7mm, simple] {
/ -> unsigned integer[nonterminal] -- p1 -> "." [terminal] -- p2 -> digit[terminal] --
p3 -- p4 -- p5 -> E[terminal] -- q1 ->[vh path]
{[nodes={yshift=7mm}]
"+"[terminal], q2, "-"[terminal]
} -> [hv path]
q3 -- /unsigned integer [nonterminal] -- p6 -> /;
p1 ->[skip loop=5mm] p4;
p3 ->[skip loop=-5mm] p2;
p5 ->[skip loop=-11mm] p6;
q1 -- q2 -- q3; % make these edges plain
};

\end{document}
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Your code works OK with PGF version 3.0.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Are you compiling with LuaTeX, XeTeX or pdfTeX or...? It compiles for me no matter, but I get different output with XeLateX than I do with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It shows:pgfkeys: _I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/grow right sep' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. };_. I re-installed the software right now and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Your code comes from pgfmanual *v3.0* and can't work with pgf *v2.10*...

Comment: you are right. I updated my whole package libraries last night and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by trying to use new code with out-of-date packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I updated my package libraries and it works now. It's necessary to update package libraries after installing the MikTex software. Thank you Gonzalo, cfr, and Paul^_^